# Change geometry for 'empty' page style only

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change \textwidth and \textheight in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13449/change-textwidth-and-textheight-in-mid-document)
>   [Change page layout after first page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65571/change-page-layout-after-first-page)

I need to make the margins on the first page of my article larger than those on the rest of the pages. I use `\thispagestyle{empty}` for the first page and `\pagestyle{fancy}` for all the other pages. So, since the first page uses a separate page style, I thought of a way to change this particular page style or maybe *redefine* it in such a way that it would have different margin sizes.

Is there a (simple, if it is possible) way to achieve this?

Comment: The page *style* is not the page *layout*. The style refers to the content of header and footer. If and how you can change the layout of your first page easily depends on the content. Is it a title page? Do you know where the page break will be?

Comment: No, this page is not a separate _titlepage_. And in general case, I don't know where the page ends. That's the problem. Because otherwise, I would use the `\newgeometry` command.