# different type areas on even/odd pages

Tags: margins, double-sided, typearea

in some (very rare) cases, it might be desirable to have the type area, particularly the text width, be different on even and odd pages. Let's say we're typesetting a textbook that's supposed to have small illustrations or annotations in the margin of the odd pages -- so we'd need a narrower type area on these. Like this:

[image: different type areas even/odd]
Here's an attempt at a solution I came up with. It isn't as smart as I thought it was. I thought we might just combine `everyshi` and an `\ifthispageodd` test to change the typearea at every shipout. Obviously, that's not how it works:

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize,10pt,DIV=12,twoside=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{everyshi,blindtext}
\EveryShipout{%
\ifthispageodd{\areaset{6cm}{12cm}}{\areaset{9cm}{12cm}}}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

this results in:

```
! Bad space factor (0).
<recently read> \@savsf 

l.7 \Blinddocument
```

Is there a way to improve this? Or something entirely different?

Comment: At the very least, this is highly non-trivial because of the asynchronous manner in which TeX works. Page breaking happens separately from paragraph building, and feeding information from the latter into the former will require some very advanced TeX hackery indeed. I am not saying it can't be done, however … Maybe I *should* say so, to provoke someone into proving me wrong.

Comment: It is massively complicated to do this in TeX, you need to save the entire paragraph (for each paragraph) then you need to detect how far into the paragraph the page break happens and then re-set the paragraph with a parshape that uses wide lines for n-lines and short lines for the rest. It gets more complicated still if you allow paragraphs longer than a page as then you need a `\parshape` that chages the length at each break.

Comment: That's about what I expected. I know the paragraph building and page breaking are interrelated in a way that makes this enterprise a bit difficult (which is why I wasn't too surprised my solution didn't work that way). Another thing I had in mind is the `flowfram` package, but I've never used it and don't know enought about it (yet) to tell if it's of any use here. Maybe someone does?

Comment: In the hope of easing your angst, a simple question: why would you *not*  want small illustrations or annotations in the margins of *even* pages, too?

Comment: I've asked that kind of question many times myself, in reply to people asking if x is possible in *TeX: »why do you want that in the first place? You might as well stop wanting it and be a happier wo/man«. But then again, if DE Knuth had been given that answer in the 70s when he asked if x is possible in phototypesetting, and if he had followed that advice and kept the things he wanted within the constraints of what's possible, we'd probably still be using Linotrons.
As for my angst: it isn't that bad. It's a fictitious scenario, fortunately. I'd like know if it were possible and at what cost.

Comment: That's so true...

Comment: @NilsL In the flowfram manual the first point of section 8.2 answers your question. In short flowfram runs into the same problem.

Comment: Frank Mittelbach in the [TeX.sx chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends): [“I'm going to answer this one during the next days \[…\]”](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8848401#8848401)

Comment: It seems to me that this may result in a document that will never be typeset properly. For example, suppose on the even LaTeX runs a float is moved from Page X (an odd page) to Page Y (an even page). On the odd LaTeX runs, the same float may be moved back from Page Y to Page X. All this moving to and fro may be caused by space restrictions on the even/odd pages that have different sizes. I mentioned the document will never be typeset properly because the relevant list of floats will always be incorrect.

Comment: There are some comments to this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65766/10038) which suggests that it is possible and that DocScape implements it. Since the players are way above my head and not chiming in here (yet), I will assume it is non-trivial.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Yep, correct. DocScape does this with TeX behind, in the manner David suggests: When a paragraph breaks "off" from one page to the next, it will be re-typeset with a parshape to reflect the new width. Note however that DocScape has a page model which is at the same time richer and poorer than that of LaTeX. For instance, in DocScape, paragraphs like to go in a fixed place on the page immediately after being typeset.

Comment: If you're willing to set all page breaks manually, this can be done with `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`. But I suspect you want something automatic?

Comment: yep... a manual solution isn't going to be a problem, and can even be done [out of the box,](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kaWyD5HY) without `geometry` or anything.

Comment: I tried to automate it with `background` and `everyshi`, without luck (only errors). `everypage` almost does the trick, but there only one margin is changed, thus printing over the page border.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This only works for simple cases, but could be extended and generalised a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\def\a{Cat dog goat sheep pig rabbit cow kangeroo. }
\def\b{One two three four five six. }
\def\c{\a\a\b\a\b\b\a\a\a\a\b\b\a\b}
\def\d{\c\par\a\b\c\par\b\b\b\b\b\b\par}
\def\e{\par\d\d\b\b\b\b\b\d\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\d}


\def\shp#1{%
\@tempcnta\z@
\loop
\advance\@tempcnta\@ne
\edef\pshape{\pshape 0pt #1 }
\ifnum\@tempcnta<46
\repeat
\advance\@tempcntb46
}
\begin{document}

{
\@tempcntb\z@
\def\pshape{}
\shp{5in}\shp{3in}
\shp{5in}\shp{3in}
\shp{5in}\shp{3in}
\def\par{\ifhmode\\\fi\hspace*{\parindent}\ignorespaces}
\show\pshape
\parshape\@tempcntb\pshape
\e\e
\endgraf
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like the number of pages and lines per page are hardwired. Is this correct? Could you use something like the lastpage package to automate the number of pages and the lineno package to get the lines per page?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub lines per page is hardwired to `46` that could be set in the preamble by dividing `\textheight` by `\baselineskip` as written it only allows 6 pages before you have to have a _real_ paragraph break and new page then start again. You could add as many `\shp` commands as you need but depending on the page size you can not have more than 20 or so as otherwise you will exceed the capacity of TeX's paragraph builder. Really each paragraph should be set as a new TeX primitive paragraph with a parshape depending on the position on the current page, but that can be hard to do

Comment: Small suggestion: If you load the `lipsum` package, you could change your `\e\e` to `\lipsum[1-26]`.

Comment: @JohnWickerson I'm having a one man crusade against the lipsum package:-)

Comment: Lorem ipsum....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What I find interesting is the contrast between (a) Frank's [saying](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8848401#8848401) that it may not be solvable at all, as well as other people saying it's extremely complicated and (b) your rather straightforward (if limited) solution. I'd love to hear Frank's ideas as well (someday, probably not within the bounty deadline).

Comment: as for the limitations: I've tried to find out if your solution accepts any `\section`ing, but whereever I put my `\section` commands, it didn't go too well. What do you think it would take to make your code compatible with them?

Comment: @NilsL this sets everything as one paragraph with a parshape designed to fit the page breaks so you either need to design a sectioning command that similarly uses forced linebreaks rather than a new paragraph (not too hard probably) or you have to do a more complete job that allowed multilple pararaphs and at the start of each mone measured where you are and set up a new parshape to fit the rest of the current page, that's a lot harder and harder still if you allow latex floats to float in and change the space left on the page. To do a really proper job you would have to rewrite half of latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle seeing your answer makes me think it is not that hard. The lineno package will let you know how many lines are on each page and let you label the first/last line of every paragraph. This should be all the info you need to set the parshape. This of course depends on lineno working with parshape.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub @DavidCarlisle okay, I'm beginning to understand what your code actually does and why (and to understand that `\parshape` is good for more than gimmicks). I still think this issue might deserve even more attention, but I'd say it's definitely a solution as defined by Daniel, and one I like a lot, particularly because it's so instructive regarding TeX's paragraph algorithms `:)`