# Different margins for odd and even pages, but not mirrored with memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, double-sided, geometry

I need a help with this page layout:

- top/bottom margins: 2cm for all pages
- on even pages: 3.5cm - 2cm
- on odd pages:  2cm - 2cm

I tried:

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2cm}{2cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

But  this doesn't resolve my problem. What's is the solution using `memoir` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: have you tried to use the geometry package?

Comment: If you're writing a book/report (or similar), this may not a good idea because floats may move from even pages to odd and back on subsequent compilations, without reaching a fixpoint.

Comment: if [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99103/different-type-areas-on-even-odd-pages) is what you want, this is a problem TeX can't solve; you might be better off with a professional DTP application.

Comment: As long as you don't require the paper size to change within the document, a combination of the `geometry` and `everypage` packages should do the trick...

Comment: @Jubobs: Have you seen that work? Comments like [these](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99103/different-type-areas-on-even-odd-pages#comment214006_99103), and my experience described in that question, suggest that it isn't that easy.

Comment: @NilsL No, I haven't found anything of the sort yet, but I still don't think it's impossible.

Comment: the reason this can't work is that when TeX starts breaking a paragraph, it doesn't yet know about the change of type area that you're planning for the upcoming page break. That's partly because TeX doesn't even *want* to know about that page break at all. It breaks a paragraph into lines, and only after that's done, it distributes the lines over the page(s). Paragraph breaking and page breaking are two separate things in TeX, and you can't just feed information to and fro between the two. [»none of the experts in the last 20 years overcame that limitation«](http://goo.gl/dPbH9)

Comment: @Nils I stand corrected. Thanks for the link.