# How to set different width of columns?

Tags: multicol

I would like to use a multicol package and create three columns with different widths, e.g. 30%, 30% and 40% of the total \textwidth.

How to do this?

### Edit:

More concretely, I am also using `\columnbreak` and I have three distinct sections that I want to see on one page split vertically and flushed left each separately. However, I want them to have different widths, small separation and distinct division like a full vertical line.

Comment: What is the context here? Is this for a stand-alone document consisting of only two pages? See the [`flowfram` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram); with some manual work you can make this happen...

Comment: or you could just use three parboxes, or a longtable or tabular with three columns. if text is not flowing from one column to the other then there is no requirement to have equal widths at all.

Comment: It is consisted of one text with its two translations (3 columns). I need to have every line of the original text aligned with the corresponding line in the other two columns. I want to write every column separately in tex as they are in very different languages.

Comment: You can use flowfram, but you have to be careful not to break a paragraph (or you can manually add a \nopar as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163075/how-to-arrange-a-large-picture-on-the-side-on-the-current-page/163104?s=1|0.2046#163104).

Answer (score 2):

That is not supported, for the same reason you can not change `\textwidth` mid document, the paragraphs are set *first* to a specified width and then split into columns, so the lines can not be re-set to a different length.

---

from your edit it looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
>{\hsize.3\hsize}X|
>{\hsize.3\hsize}X|
>{\hsize.4\hsize}X}
aaa

\[x=y\]
&
bbb

xx
zz

&ccc
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

will do what you want. (`tabularx` package)

Comment: It makes sense.

Comment: I have made an edit that better explains what I would like to do.

Comment: @Vladimir see update

Comment: This would require to write one line from the first column, then one line from the second and then from the third, before starting the second line, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Vladimir No! write all  the first column text then `&` then all the second column then `&` then the third. `X` columns can take multiple paragraphs.

Comment: I appreciate your help! This package is unfamiliar to me. It gives me an error: Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>   >   1.19 >{\hsize.4\hsize}X}

Comment: @Vladimir sorry I got the syntax wrong.  (even though it's my package:-)

Comment: Your code works (obviously). However, what happened to the old syntax requirement that the sum of the `\hsize` arguments had to be equal to the sum of the `X`-type columns? I would have thought that 0.9, 0.9, and 1.2 had to be the `\hsize` arguments, but that's evidently (no more?) the case. Did you change the syntax requirement(s) at some point?

Comment: @Mico that's an interesting question!  It's an old answer so I'm not sure: either I was tired and couldn't add up, or I was following  the documentation on the last line of section 4.3 of the `tabularx` doc...... Nothing has changed in the `tabularx` algorithm since the 1990s