# Text on the left side and picture on the right side

Tags: two-column

I would like to know which command I should use with **MiKTex** to put text on the left side and a picture on the right side. I tried this command below but it doesn't work .

```
\begin{columns}{2}
\column{.45\linewidth}
$\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Quadrilateres.png}$

\column{.45\linewidth}

text...text
\end{columns}
```

Comment: Try the minipage environment. And please remove the math mode around `\includegraphics`.

Comment: This is a common issue, especially if you want to wrap the text around the picture..  Check the related questions to the right, search here for wrapfig.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348801/remove-additional-space-added-after-wrapfigure-environment/348865?s=6|14.2326#348865