# Multicols: how to modify the width for each column

Tags: multicol, posters

I am writing a poster and I am using the multicols environment in order to divide each section. The poster is organized in horizontal sections and each one is organized in two or more columns. For only one horizontal section I would like to have three columns, the first two of which should be smaller (width) than the third one. For this section, I am currently using the following:

```
\fbox{

\parbox{1.014\boxwidth}{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.005\textwidth}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.00125\textwidth}
\setlength{\columnwidth}{1.02\linewidth}

\newpart{Results \& Discussion}

\vbox to 0.375\textheight {%
\raggedcolumns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.pt}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{center}
   \heading{Some title}
\end{center}

{Some text}

\begin{center}
   \heading{Some title}
\end{center}

{Some text}

\begin{center}
   \heading{Some title}
\end{center}

{Some text}

\end{multicols}
```

Is it possible to maintain what I have done and just modify the width of the first two columns? Would it be possible to modify just this section to use different width sizes using another package?

Comment: multicol is designed for automatic column breaking and balancing so all the columns have to be the same width, for a poster you can use different size `\parbox`

Comment: You can try to check: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/different-column-widths-using-multicol

Comment: You could do it using flowfram, but it should be noted that when a paragraph is broken across columns of different widths it won't adapt.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163075/how-to-arrange-a-large-picture-on-the-side-on-the-current-page/163104?s=1|0.4021#163104 for example.