# Put figure(s) in a full-height area on the side of a page

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I have a landscape book and I figured out that it would make sense to put figures on the side of pages as illustrated in the following image:

[image]

I know that there are wrap figures, but as far as I know, they are positioned relative to a paragraph, and I want to have a dedicated area on the side of a page.

Comment: the nearest latex offers by default is \marginpar

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `flowfram` package.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer but as far as I can tell, `flowfram` redefines many things such as figures, tables, chapters. That’s a bit unfortunate because I already have all the things defined for the book

Comment: You illustration suggests that you are looking for an automatic way to change the width of the text block for each page. I don't see how you can achieve this within `book`. (And to be honest it doesn't seem straightforward with `flowfram` either.) Maybe some advanced `luatex` wizardry could do it.

Comment: Even with flowfram you have a problem when a paragraph breaks between two columns with different widths.  I suspect the only real solution is to manually break the paragraphs (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163075/how-to-arrange-a-large-picture-on-the-side-on-the-current-page/163104?s=1|36.7830#163104) and use minipages.

Comment: Actually, wrapfigure will do the job, but again, you have to insert it precisely where the paragraph breaks (and pad the figure to \textheight).